# Simpy logging data to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object, simpy

I created a simple class with the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import simpy

class Seller(object):
    _s_list = []     # list of all sellers
    s_df = pd.DataFrame() # log dataframe

    def __init__ (self, env, name):
         self._s_list.append(self)
        self.env, self.name = env, name
        self.action = env.process(self.do_somehting())

    def do_somehting(self):
        while True:
            self.s_df=self.s_df.append(
                pd.DataFrame.from_dict([{
                "time":self.env.now,
                "name":self.name,
                }]))
            # print(len(self.s_df))
            yield self.env.timeout(1)

    @classmethod
    def lst(self):
        return self._s_list

    @classmethod
    def df(self):
        return self.s_df

env = simpy.Environment()
for i in range(0,3):
    Seller(env, "seller n. %d" % i)
env.run(until=5)
print(Seller.lst(), Seller.df())
```

the code above creates three Sellers and since when they are created each cycle they do_somehting.
I would like to capture their status at each cycle, and to store related information inside a dataframe.
My issue is that the `s_df` dataframe is empty outside the do_somehting function. If I query the `s_df` dataframe within the do_somehting function I see that data are available, and in particular that a row is added for each Seller and each cycle. However if I simply run the code below after the cycles have terminated:

```
Seller.df()
```

I get an empty dataframe.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "I am not able to access the s_df dataframe outside the grow function". And please reformat the code to make it more readable (PEP8: https://pep8.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your interest! I tried to make the question more clear.

Comment: is self.s_df=self.s_df.append( creating a instance variable?  Try Seller.s_df=self.s_df.append(

Comment: So the problem is in the SimPy, because without it everything is correct. Doesn’t SimPy store copies of Seller class and created sellers in its environment?

Answer (score 2):

in do_something() self.s_df is not the class variable, its a instance variable.  Use Seller.s_df to get the class variable.  Also in class methods it better to use cls instead of self.

```
import pandas as pd
import simpy

class Seller(object):
    _s_list = []     # list of all sellers
    s_df = pd.DataFrame() # log dataframe

    def __init__ (self, env, name):
        self._s_list.append(self)
        self.env, self.name = env, name
        self.action = env.process(self.do_somehting())

    def do_somehting(self):
        while True:
            Seller.s_df=Seller.s_df.append(
                pd.DataFrame.from_dict([{
                "time":self.env.now,
                "name":self.name,
                }]))
            # print(len(self.s_df))
            print(f'{self.env.now:0.2f} {self.name}')
            yield self.env.timeout(1)

    @classmethod
    def lst(self):
        return self._s_list

    @classmethod
    def df(self):
        return self.s_df

env = simpy.Environment()
for i in range(0,3):
    Seller(env, f"seller {i}")
env.run(until=5)
print(Seller.lst(), Seller.df())
```